# Splitting fields in sql query and sorting by them

Tags: mysql, split, field

I have a field containg a combined date, something line 2012-02-03 - 2012-02-05 where the first date is the "from" date, and second is the "to" date.

Is there a way that I can split these two dates and then order by the "from" date ?

I know the best thing would be to have two different fields for these two dates, but since I began doing it this way there is alot of recoding to seperate them.

Comment: which `datetype` you have used for that column?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) for this.

Assuming your dates have ' - ' between them (i.e. space, hypen, space), you can do something like:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(datefield,' - ',1) as fromDate,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(datefield,' - ',-1) as toDate,
FROM ..
ORDER BY DATE(fromDate)
```

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(string,delimiter,count)` returns all of `string` up to (not including) the `count`th occurence of `delimiter`. If `delimiter` is negative it counts from the right and returns the substring from the end of the string instead.

I used `DATE(fromDate)` to convert `fromDate` from a string to a MySQL Date so it sorts in a date-like fashion.

Answer (score 1):

or, if your dates have exactly 10 characters lenght, you can use SUBSTRING as follows http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53006/4

Answer (score 1):

You can you [left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) and [right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) function to get the 10 digit from left in that column and 10 digit from right in column, using alias from_date and to_date then order by.

```
2012-02-03 - 2012-02-05
__________   __________
 Left 10      Right 10 
 Digits       Digits


SELECT LEFT(mydate,10) AS from_date,
       RIGHT(mydate,10) AS to_date
       FROM mytable
       ORDER BY from_date,to_date;
```