# how to order my string column using substr and cast in mysql

Tags: mysql

my column id data is like :

```
99999/1
99999/2
99999/5
99999/10
99999/8
99999/4
....
```

when i use

```
order by cast(SUBSTR(id,7) as unsigned)
```

my data order likes:

```
999999/4
999999/3
999999/5
999999/6
999999/1
999999/7
999999/8
999999/9
999999/10
999999/11
999999/12
999999/13
999999/14
999999/15
999999/16
999999/17
999999/18
999999/19
```

how do I can order this column `id` by second part numbers exist after '/' character

Comment: Please take a moment to familiarize yourself with [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so we can read your questions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting fields in sql query and sorting by them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529198/splitting-fields-in-sql-query-and-sorting-by-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order it by the first part and then the second part:

```
order by cast(substring_index(id,'/',1) as unsigned),cast(substring_index(id,'/',-1) as unsigned)
```

To order only by the second part, just:

```
order by cast(substring_index(id,'/',-1) as unsigned)
```